# Why is there 4.86(maybe 15.1) GB of USED-space on a newly partitioned and formatted 298 GB drive (as ext4 by Gparted)

Tags: partitioning, format

Well the question says most of it...

Gparted reports the used space as 4.86 GB
Nautilus reports used space as 15.1 GB...(via Properties of /media/U_0298_data)

Why is this space **used**?  and who is reporting the correct figure? (...if either)
Is this related to the **Trash**?

PS. It is the only partition, and is using the entire drive space.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gparted, that use mkfs.ext4 to create a ext4 filesystem, reserves 5% of the space for super-user, as explained in man page:

```
-m reserved-blocks-percentage
   Specify  the  percentage  of the filesystem blocks reserved for the super-user.  This 
   avoids fragmentation, and allows root-owned daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to 
   function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the 
   filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.
```

Now, 5% of about 300GB is just the 15GB you see already used.

More interesting, you can avoid this if you feel do not need it, simply creating the filesystem with, for example,

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 /dev/sda1
```

where 0 means 0%.

I think Gparted see more space because is run by super-user, so part of that 15GB are free for him. Nautilus is run by the user, so the space is less.

Comment: Grazie mille...

Comment: You can also reset the reserved percentage after you create the filesystem with tune2fs. The syntax is essentially the same: `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1`.

Answer (score 5):

There are different ways of counting space on a filesystem ranging from bytes not in use to free clusters, etc. In the absence of better information, I'd take gparted's report as more "accurate".

Filesystems require overhead for i-tables, free lists, superblocks, superblock backups, and - in ext4 - journaling. Your reported 4.86 out of 298GB is a whopping 1.6% overhead in order to keep track of your stuffs; that strikes me as pretty low overhead.

Comment: *low* overhead? Ouch!

Comment: I have a pretty similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48488 Its a 250GiB parition, so figures are similar. Nautilus show 188MB of used space, and a total capacity thats 4GB smaller than actual. Which one is the overhead? And what is the other?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the space reserved for root, see my other answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48488/ext4-partition-size-free-space-discrepancies/48511#48511).  The short of it is that the ext series of filesystems reserves space for the inode tables at format time, which with the default settings, amounts to 2 mb for every 128 mb of disk space.