# Unable to write to ext4, No space left on device?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, 14.10, encryption, ext4

After creating a folder in my ext4 partition, copying some data to it, then moving that whole folder to another drive, I became unable to add additional data to the ext4 partition when I boot into Linux.

Access via Windows was enabled for me through Paragon ExtFS for Windows.

I can delete files, but not add new ones. Booting into my LiveUSB, I did a partition check using GParted, however that didn't fix this issue. There is >1GB free space on this partition.

#### How can I add new data when logged into my Linux partition?

Comment: What partitions can you not write to? Have a `lsblk` / `mount` to check? Tried using a program like `baobab` to see how big each folder is?

Comment: The only partition I cannot write to is my ext4 SSD one from my Ubuntu partition (that same one). Is there some migration path, e.g.: I move the partition somewhere else, install Ubuntu 14.10 x64 then migrate everything over?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the ext4 drive/folders?

Comment: Yes. Additionally my home is encrypted (but I can `ls`, `cat` and `rm` no worries one logged into e.g.: tty1)

Comment: Try pasting the output of `df -T` (and `lsblk` & `mount` wouldn't hurt either), maybe there's some mountpoint issues

Comment: Here's the output: http://pastie.org/private/89asxiocox3trqkkaqojw. When I boot into my LiveUSB to check that partition, I note that it has over 1GB of free space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was wrong about it being an issue from somewhere else, it actually wasn't a corruption issue! Fixed via [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/63255/25184):

> After some fiddling about, I was able to reclaim a large amount of space with `tune2fs`:

```
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ df -h | grep sdc
/dev/sdc1             1.8T  1.7T  352M 100% /media/data
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1 | grep 'Reserved block count'
Reserved block count:     24418900
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdc1
tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1 | grep 'Reserved block count'
Reserved block count:     0
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ df -h | grep sdc
/dev/sdc1             1.8T  1.7T   94G  95% /media/data
```

> Apparently linux reserve 5% of new partitions for the root user and system services, so that when you run out of disk space, root can still log in and clean stuff up with system services running ok. Seems kind of bananas to me when the system services only need a hundred meg or so, and 5% of a 2TB drive is a $h17load more than that.. *shrugs*
>
> This left me with 93.5 GB free, which still leaves about 30 gig unaccounted for, so if anyone has any more ideas feel free to chip in!